# Read multiple RDS-files with similarly name yyyySummary, where yyyy is 2010 to 2020

Tags: r

I have multiple RDS-files, which were similarly named. The names of the files are:

- 2010Summary.RDS
- 2011Summary.RDS
- 2012Summary.RDS
- ...
- 2020Summary.RDS

Now I want to read all of them in R into a data table, how can I do that?
Somehow like: `dt.summary <- base::readRDS(file = paste0(filePath, "?Summary.RDS"))`

I hope someone can help me with this issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
files <- list.files("/path_to_files/", pattern = "^\\d{4}Summary.RDS$")

mydata <- files |> 
    purrr::map(readRDS) |>
    list_rbind()
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this answer. All RDS-files have the same column structure and I want to combine the data from 2010 to 2020 row by row.

Comment: The script reads the file names in your folder and combines them into one data frame.  Is this not what you want?

Comment: I want to read all RDS-files which are similary named and not other RDS-files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution.

```
sprintf("%dSummary.RDS", 2010:2020) |>
  lapply(readRDS) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this answer. All RDS-files have the same column structure and I want to combine the data from 2010 to 2020 row by row.

Comment: @MikiK That's exactly what the last instruction does, it calls `rbind` on the list of data.frames read in by `readRDS` outputting only one df.